SwiftData Cascade delete results in N+1 queries?
I have a very simple one-to-many relationship between two models where a Trail has many Coordinates. This relationship is configured with cascading deletes. However, when I delete a single Trail, I get N+1 delete queries.
@Model
final class Trail {
    var name: String
    var draft: Bool
    var createdAt: Date
    var startedAt: Date?
    var endedAt: Date?
    var notes: String
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var coordinates: [Coordinate] // <-- Relationship
    
    init(name: String, coordinates: [Coordinate], draft: Bool = true, startedAt: Date? = nil, endedAt: Date? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.draft = draft
        self.startedAt = startedAt
        self.endedAt = endedAt
        self.createdAt = Date.now
        self.notes = ""
        self.coordinates = coordinates
    }
}

@Model
final class Coordinate {
    var order: Int
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
    var altitude: Double?
    var recordedAt: Date?
    var createdAt: Date
    
    init(_ latitude: Double, _ longitude: Double, altitude: Double? = nil, recordedAt: Date? = nil, order: Int = 0) {
        self.order = order
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.altitude = altitude
        self.recordedAt = recordedAt
        self.createdAt = Date.now
    }
}

The delete code looks like this
    func handleDeleteTrail(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        offsets.forEach { offset in
            modelContext.delete(filteredTrails[offset])
        }
        do {
            try modelContext.save()
        } catch let error {
            Logger.main.error("Failed to delete trail(s) with error: \(error)")
        }
    }

It's actually 2(N+1) since it also creates individual inserts into the change history table for each operation.
Is there an easy way to optimize this? Why would SwiftData not do a batch delete by default?

Maybe you have answered this within your question, to be able to store change information for each object SwiftData needs to delete them individually? Is this a real world performance issue for you, in such case you might experiment with manually deleting the objects using delete(model:where:) and see if it’s better or perhaps wait for the next version (iOS 18 etc) where I believe there is some batch delete functionality.

Some of my models have over 1000 coordinates so it does become a very noticeable performance problem. I wasn’t expecting to have to craft a background thread strategy for this. Manually deleting using a strategy like this is what I’ll have to do I guess. Can I turn off change information?
